# White screen shown when keyboard is open on TextField

Tags: flutter

Below is the image that contains a `TextField` and a `ListView`. When I clicked on `TextField` to type something keyboard is opened with white screen. I want to remove this white screen when keyboard is open.

I tried the following lines but none of them worked:

```
resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
```

[image]

Here is my code.

```
return Scaffold
  (
  backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
  //resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
  body: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        new Container(
          height: 80.0,
        child: new Row(
          //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          //mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Expanded(
              child: new Padding(
                padding: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 0.0, top: 0.0),
                child: TextField(
                  autocorrect: false,
                  key: homeScaffoldKey,
                  controller: _location_city,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Search by location or zipcode",
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                  ),

                ),

        ),

            ),

            new Padding(
              padding: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 0.0),
              //onPressed will show login with the username typed on terminal
              child: new FlatButton(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 15.0),
                  color: Colors.blue[100],
                  onPressed: ()  {
                   

                  }, child: new Text('Filter', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.blue),),
                  shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0))
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
  ),

        Expanded(
            child: FutureBuilder(
                  future: getData(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot)
                  {
                    return snapshot.data != null
                        ? listViewWidget(snapshot.data)
                        : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  }
              ),
        ),
      ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: What was the outcome of  `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false`?

Comment: same as shown in the image.

Comment: I guess we need to do a bit of an experiment then. `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true` leads to?

Comment: Yes, I experimented with it also I used Singlechildscrollview to remove the white screen when keyboard is opened.

Comment: Did you find any solution for that? I have the same issue with flutter web on Safari.

Comment: Same issue on Android Devices, but not on iOS

Answer (score 0):

go to your Scaffold widget then set `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false`